# How does Windows change Aero Glass color?

Tags: colors, aero, dwm

I'm using Windows 7 RTM and I wonder how the control panel is able to update the Aero Glass color so smoothly without restarting the DWM (uxsms). DwmSetColorizationColor isn't working any more...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following methods should be of interest to you:

```cs
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#127", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void DwmGetColorizationParameters(out WDM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters);
    
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#131", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void DwmSetColorizationParameters(WDM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters, uint uUnknown);
    
public struct WDM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS {
    public uint Color1;
    public uint Color2;
    public uint Intensity;
    public uint Unknown1;
    public uint Unknown2;
    public uint Unknown3;
    public uint Opaque;
}
```

Make sure you make a call to `DwmIsCompositionEnabled` before calling the `DwmSetColorizationParameters` method or it will fail.

As you can see some of the arguments/properties are unknown.
For more information, here is a [link (in German)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/windows7de/thread/ad570e44-a221-484d-836e-6e3c146080c0)

Comment: +1 to counteract a stupd -1. This answer is an answer to the question "How does it do..."  This is probably exactly how it does it.  Although i read the original question as "How *does* it do..." and not "*How* does it do..."

Comment: In Windows 7 the original method DWMSetColorization throws an exception (it was supported in Windows Vista though). I assume it was his intention to find a new method that offers the same functionality as the old one. One option is to write a .theme file and execute that or use the undocumented method I specified above.