# programmatically change the windows color border of windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Windows change Aero Glass color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487919/how-does-windows-change-aero-glass-color)

using c# how do you programmatically change the windows border color when running aero on windows 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to change the color of a window individually but you can change the color OS-wide via the resgistry. The entry should be something like this: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Glass Colorization\Swatches` in conjunction with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM - ColorizationColor`

From within your code you can only adjust the shape and the size of your Glass border but I don't think the color. In [Windows Forms it is done like](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsuidevelopment/thread/f7ffa1ee-deba-4cca-a1e5-5f737dbccd87) this and in [WPF like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975.aspx).

Comment: how do you change the color using the reg keys? do you any sample code ? :D on how to implement this? :D

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with C#/.NET. WPF/WindowsForms only allow you to change the borders on elements inside the application. Application borders are user-controlled.

Answer (score 2):

While bitbonk and george have correctly pointed out that windows is not capable of changing the border colors for individual windows, you might look into owner-drawing the window. You may then be able to achieve what you need, however, the window will most probably not look like a "native" window anymore.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460/custom-titlebarschrome-in-a-winforms-app) on SO.

Answer (score 2):

TheCardinal: Your registry method does not instantly change the colour, and requires a restart of the desktop window manager service.
There is an undocumented windows API function that allows you to change the colour of the Aero theme instantly. (this is again, a global change - applies to ALL windows)

although I do not have C# code to do this, VB.NET should help you since they are essentially the same thing

```
<DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint:="#127", PreserveSig:=False)> _
Public Shared Sub DwmGetColorizationParameters(ByRef parameters As WDM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS)
End Sub
//this above function GETS the color, and stores it in parameters.
<DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint:="#131", PreserveSig:=False)> _
Public Shared Sub DwmSetColorizationParameters(ByRef parameters As WDM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS, ByVal uUnknown As UInteger)
End Sub
//this above function SETS the color, and stores it in parameters.
```

and finally the struct WDM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS is defined as such (again in VB.NET, sorry)

```
Public Structure WDM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS
    Public Color1 As Int32
    Public Color2 As Int32
    Public Intensity As Int32
    Public Unknown1 As Int32
    Public Unknown2 As Int32
    Public Unknown3 As Int32
    Public Opaque As Long
End Structure
```

code logic would be as follows:

```
WDM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS temp = getColor();
temp.Color1 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(alpha,red,green,blue).ToArgb();
temp.Color2 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(alpha,red,green,blue).ToArgb();
setColor(temp);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You can always convert from C# to VB.NET or vice versa using [Developer Fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) :)