# Is there a way to change windows7 aero theme with python?

Tags: python, windows-7, aero

I want to create a script that will change the global Aero window border color based on certain conditions. Say, for example, a tasks completes in the background, it could change the  global window glass to a green hue, for a subtle notification.

There seems to be a way to do it [through Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172289/496097), but not knowing VB, I was wondering if someone knew a way to do it with Python... or another scripting language.

Comment: Well the VB code just calls [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (the interesting counterpart doesn't seem to be public though?) - so that can easily be done using ctypes.

Comment: Voo, thank you for that great head start!!! Anyone have any ideas how to access the undocumented setter function?

Comment: Well on my win7 install DwmpSetColorizationColor is implemented as follows: `mov eax, 80004001h; retn 0Ch` so that doesn't work any longer. So you'll have to do the setting manually and trace what function calls happen. Then a bit of reverse engineering should do the trick. Slightly harder than looking up the documentation and calling the function, but well that's to be expected isn't it?

Comment: I guess this is what happens when a front-end web guy gets for thinking outside the box. :) You've gone way over my head. Any chance you can bring it down a couple of levels?

Comment: I fear that was already the high level overview without all the nitty gritty details. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2007/04/14/windbg-script-tracing-api-calls.aspx) should get you started on finding out how to find the actual call that is changing the color. If you have that you can either stay with the "set things manually and check what the arguments to the function are" or try to generalize it so that you don't have to check for every possible color. It's probably a good idea to do that prototyping in c though