# How to get a smooth color change?

Tags: c#, colors, dwm

What would be the best way to smoothly change one color to another in c#.
My program changes the user's color scheme according to battery level.

My current code 
         `private void greater75_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)`
        `{`

```
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 && DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
        {
            PowerStatus ps = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;
            if (ps.BatteryLifePercent >= 0.75)
            {
                ChangeCol.clrAfterGlow = 5;
                ChangeCol.clrColor = ColorToBgra(Color.Green);
                ChangeCol.nIntensity += 1;
                DwmSetColorizationParameters(ref ChangeCol, false);
            }
            if (ps.BatteryLifePercent < 0.75)
            {
                ChangeCol.clrAfterGlow = 5;
                ChangeCol.clrColor = ColorToBgra(Color.Blue);
                ChangeCol.nIntensity += 1;
                DwmSetColorizationParameters(ref ChangeCol, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is using this struct and methods to modify the user's system color.

Thanks to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17808712/2609115) and [this other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1813169)

```
    public DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS ChangeCol;
    public struct DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS
    {
        public uint clrColor;
        public uint clrAfterGlow;
        public uint nIntensity;
        public uint clrAfterGlowBalance;
        public uint clrBlurBalance;
        public uint clrGlassReflectionIntensity;
        public bool fOpaque;
    }


    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#127", PreserveSig = false)]
    private static extern void DwmGetColorizationParameters(out DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters);

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#131", PreserveSig = false)]
    private static extern void DwmSetColorizationParameters(ref DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters,
                                                            bool unknown);

    // Helper method to convert from a Win32 BGRA-format color to a .NET color.
    private static Color BgraToColor(uint color)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(Int32.Parse(color.ToString("X"), NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    }

    // Helper method to convert from a .NET color to a Win32 BGRA-format color.
    private static uint ColorToBgra(Color color)
    {
        return (uint)(color.B | (color.G << 8) | (color.R << 16) | (color.A << 24));
    }
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();
    // Gets or sets the current color used for DWM glass, based on the user's color scheme.

    public static Color ColorizationColor
    {
        get
        {
            // Call the DwmGetColorizationParameters function to fill in our structure.
            DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters;
            DwmGetColorizationParameters(out parameters);

            // Convert the colorization color to a .NET color and return it.
            return BgraToColor(parameters.clrColor);
        }
        set
        {
            // Retrieve the current colorization parameters, just like we did above.
            DWM_COLORIZATION_PARAMS parameters;
            DwmGetColorizationParameters(out parameters);

            // Then modify the colorization color.
            // Note that the other parameters are left untouched, so they will stay the same.
            // You can also modify these; that is left as an exercise.
            parameters.clrColor = ColorToBgra(value);

            // Call the DwmSetColorizationParameters to make the change take effect.
            DwmSetColorizationParameters(ref parameters, false);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when setting a color, and making it's intensity increase by one every 0.1 seconds after setting it to 0, when at 0 , the intensity is BLACK , I want a somewhat 'smooth' transition to the new color, so that it won't abruptly distract the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerp_%28computing%29) or [polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) interpolation. Both should produce a smooth transition. If you want a more gradual, tapered off effect you can use [logarithmic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale#Logarithmic_interpolation).

Every 0.1 seconds might seem unsmooth to most people since it's technically 10 frames-per-second. I'd maybe try updating every 0.05-0.03 seconds (*20-30 FPS*).

Hope that helps.